# AWS Fargate Connection Refused on Local Loopback 127.0.0.1

Tags: docker, aws-fargate

I'm trying to simply get one Linux Docker container running a React app to call a NodeJS, express API running on a separate Linux Docker container within AWS Fargate. Here is the guidance article I've been following for networking:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/task-networking-in-aws-fargate/

These are the port mappings from the task definition for the NodeJS container:

```
"portMappings": [
            {
                "name": "xxxx-backend-8001-tcp",
                "containerPort": 8001,
                "hostPort": 8001,
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "appProtocol": "http"
            }
        ],
```

Here are the port mappings from the task definition for the React container (though not sure it really matters in this case):

```
            "portMappings": [
            {
                "name": "xxxx-frontend-90-tcp",
                "containerPort": 90,
                "hostPort": 90,
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "appProtocol": "http"
            }
        ],
```

For the NodeJS container, I have port 8001 exposed in the dockerfile. I'm able to hit the API endpoints on port 8001 once I have the task deployed in a cluster, as well. However, looking at the browser debugger, whenever the react app tries hitting any of the endpoints using [http://127.0.0.1:8001/{api](http://127.0.0.1:8001/%7Bapi) endpoint here}, I get "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

This should seem straight enough from that AWS blog post linked above. Is there something simple I'm missing in the security group settings? For now while I'm learning I have the security group inbound rules for this VPC allowing all traffic with IP version IPv4, all protocols and port ranges.

Comment: "Linux Docker container running a React app": could you please expand a little bit on what exactly this means? Is it a server serving static JS pages with React code in them? A server-side app using React to render HTML? The part which is trying to connect to the Express API, does run in the browser or on the server?

Comment: "Is it a server serving static JS pages with React code in them?" -Yes
"The part which is trying to connect to the Express API, does run in the browser or on the server?" From the browser. I'm using the axios library within the react code to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You React app is just an HTTP server which is serving static pages to the browser. Itself, it does not try to connect to the Express container.

What is happening is that your users' browsers run the JS code which has been served them by the React app. This code is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1, which is the loopback address for the machine running the browser, not that of the Express container.

Fargate does have the capability to share loopback interfaces between different containers. You requests would work had they been issued by the code running in the React container.

You should change your JS code so that it sends requests to the externally exposed address and port of the Express container, rather than to 127.0.0.1

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much.